# Pusher Notification PHP "404 NOT FOUND"

Tags: php, pusher

I need help with this error from the pusher notification package.

The API returns "404 NOT FOUND" on trying send data through HTTP POST (curl)
My code is like this:

index.php

```
<?php

require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php');
$app_id = getenv('my_app_id');
$app_key = getenv('my_app_key');
$app_secret = getenv('my_app_secred_key');
$pusher = new Pusher\Pusher($app_key, $app_secret, $app_id);
$data['message'] = 'hello world';
$test = $pusher->trigger('channel', 'event', $data, null, true);

var_dump($test);
```

The return of var_dump($test) is:

```
array(2) { ["body"]=> string(14) "404 NOT FOUND " ["status"]=> int(404) }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Double-check that your `$app_id` is correct - do a `var_dump($app_id)`.